# Bootstrap is not allowing me to add my own dimensions to a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "contact-us" element that is nested in a div on a page that uses Bootstrap.

I styled the element in the div on a seperate html page and it works exactly as intended.

I placed the element into my index.html page as my plans are to turn it into a modal. Looking at the page, the contact-us form is the improper width causing the contents to be mis-aligned. I know bootstrap is the culprit because when I comment out the cdn link for bootstrap the "contact us" form appears exactly as it is supposed to. I attempted to use the inspector to change the width of the div, and it won't allow it. The computed width shown in inspector immediately reverts back to the same dimensions when I hit Enter or click off the dimension using my mouse.

How do I force the div to respond as if bootstrap were not controlling it? Using !important on the dimensions does nothing. The following is the css I used on the div which works perfectly on a page that does not have bootstrap enabled.

```
.contact-us {
    height: 400px;
    min-width: 575px !important;
    width: 575px !important;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 10px;
    background-color: #44C1FB;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
}
```

Here is the jfiddle link. If you remove the link to the bootstrap cdn at the very top of the html file it works properly.

https://jsfiddle.net/htL0vrfL/

Comment: Please post a demo of your issue.

Comment: How do I post a demo? I am new at this.

Comment: Use bootply.com and share the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that bootstrap sets `box-sizing` to `border-box` for the elements. As of that the `div` will have the exact width of `575px` but you expect it to have an *inner width* of `575px` (the same is for your height).

If you want to change this behaviour you need to set `box-sizing` to `content-box` on your `.contact-us` [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3qu5e5g/2/).

```
.contact-us {
  box-sizing: content-box; /**   change box sizing to content-box **/
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /** only needed for Chrome before version 10 **/
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box; /** only needed for FireFox before version 29 **/
  height: 400px;
  min-width: 575px !important;
  width: 575px !important;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px 10px;
  background-color: #44C1FB;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

Or if you want to stay with `border-box` then you would need to add your `padding` to your `width` and `height`.

Beside that it might be a better solution to not set the `width` and `height` at all, but use `display: inline-block` for your `.contact-us`

Comment: How exactly do I do that? I am in my .contact-us class and I attempted to do box-sizing: content-box; and it did not work. I also tried box-sizing: 575px; and it did not work either.

Comment: @MichaelDWheeler does the fiddle I have added not work?

Comment: I just copied the code exactly and it doesn't work. It is not working on jfiddle either when I run it. If you remove the bootstrap cdn link at the top of the html you can view how it is intended to look. I also tried the display inline-block and it did not alter it either.

Comment: @MichaelDWheeler What browser and version do you use for testing?

Comment: @MichaelDWheeler for me (also chrome 44) it looks like this in the given jsfiddle [http://snag.gy/nQhil.jpg](http://snag.gy/nQhil.jpg), and the blue box looks fine here.

Comment: on the jfiddle link as well as my page it is not correct. I am not sure why it is working on the link you posted. Did you include the link to the bootstrap cdn on your version? <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: @MichaelDWheeler: It is a screenshot of the result of this [https://jsfiddle.net/o3qu5e5g/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/o3qu5e5g/2/) fiddle.

Comment: when I click the link you provided in the above comment, it still appears to be incorrect on my end. Here is a screenshot of what the link you provided looks like to me: http://imgur.com/1gf2Pzw

Comment: @MichaelDWheeler well in your screenshot the size of the blue box is exactly the same size as in the shreenshot I provided, and the same size it has if the bootstrap link is removed. The problem is now that sizing of the elements inside of the box do behave like you expect, but thats another problem. You always have to be clear about what you ask. The answer I gave you solved the initial describe problem. And it was not obvious that there are other problems that where not described by in your question.

Comment: I apologize, I realized what the real issue was and I believe you just pointed it out. I am about a month into coding so I completely overlooked it. I was applying your solution to the outer div, but I actually have an inner div that contains the email field and the name field.

Comment: @MichaelDWheeler no need to apologize. Sorry if it might sound rough. But everyone here is voluntary using sparetime to answer. If it is not obvious that there is also another problem, then it is unlikely that you will get the correct answer, especially it you say that it not working even if the given answer solved your described problem. At that point everything becomes misleading and the chance will be low that you will find a solution, as the given solution is right and it is hard to determine why you still state that there is a problem (until you posted your screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

By commenting out these lines your form seems to look correct with bootstrap activated.

```
/* -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; */
/* -moz-box-sizing: border-box; */
/* box-sizing: border-box; */
```

As mentioned in the comments, we remedy this by creating a class to overwrite the above rules.

```
.nonborderbox * { 
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box; 
  box-sizing: content-box; 
}
```

Comment: I do not have those links in my css file or my html file. Are you commenting them out from the cdn link somehow?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 uses `border-box` for everything, are you disabling those for the `*` selectors? You don't want to do that. What you may want to do, is changing that for some individual class, as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: That fixed it. I had to actually make a class: .nonborderbox *
{
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
      box-sizing: content-box;
} and then apply it to the div but it worked.

Comment: Actually it did not fix the height issue. It fixed the width but the height was still incorrect and my Send It button was off the element when I applied the code I entered right above this comment.

Comment: Apologies for my vague answer, I was short on time, since you accepted another answer I will assume there's no need to further elaborate here, however I will add your added class to the solution. It was an incomplete answer however I definitely was not advocating removing a fundamental component of bootstrap.